how add a new document to an already existing Chroma database, with open ai embeddings with langchain?
preprocess_and_structure_csv()

data = csv_load()
try:
    db = Chroma.from_documents(data, embeddings_model, persist_directory='db')
except Exception as e:
    print("An error occurred while creating the database:", str(e))

Here's my setup my data is a .csv file; I tried to make every row as documents and I want to add new rows to the database without embeddings all the .csv file.
I tried to add ids to every row of documents but I couldn't figure out how to add them without embedding. All the .csv file knowing that it will be expensive
